# Share NFS without sharing top level directory?

Tags: linux, nfs

We recently had a situation where a user could mount a top level directory even though it was not in the /etc/exports file on our RHEL server. Is there a way to stop this and only share out sub-directories?

Comment: Is this NFSv3 or NFSv4?

Comment: Either version results in the top level directory being mounted. no_root_squash and no_all_squash are on.